# Matrix Multiplication and solve_ivp

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I try to simulate a LTI system using Python. The structure is xDot = Ax. I defined the system dynamics as a function I then call using `solve_ivp`. Calling the function itself works, but simulating the system results in the following error

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)
```

for the line with the matrix multiplication in the system dynamics definition. Below is the code.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# System Parameters
l = 1 # Pendulum length
g = 9.81 # gravity

# Initial Conditions
x0 = np.array([np.pi/2, 0])

# Simulation parameters
tStart = 0
tEnd = 4
t_span = [tStart, tEnd]
t = np.linspace(tStart,tEnd,10) # Simulation time

# System matrices
A = np.array([[0, 1],[-g/l, 0]])

def dynamics(x, t):
    xdot = -A@x
    return xdot

y = integrate.solve_ivp(dynamics, t_span, x0)
```

How do I need to adjust the system definition to make this work?

Comment: Can you provide the complete stack trace please?

Comment: Shouldn't `dynamics` have the signature `dynamics(t, x)`? See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html

Comment: From https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html, I see that the first operand to `dynamics()` should be a scalar, so you can't do `A@x`. And then you ignore `t`, that doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @Nechoj I just tested your suggestion, and changing to `dynamics(t,x)` makes the program run without error. @fukurai, does that solve your problem?

Comment: @joanis: Ignoring `t` inside `dynamics` is perfectly ok. Many dynamical systems have time-independent forces.

Comment: @Nechoj Right, that makes perfect sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Nechoj: Thank you so much. That solved the problem. If you write this as an answer, I'll mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) the signature of the dynamics should be `dynamics(t, x)` with the scalar `t` as the first argument. This is how `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` calls the given dynamics.

In your case, the error is caused by the fact that the matrix `A` is multiplied with the scalar `t` and the error message `Input operand 1 does not have enough dimensions` indicates that the matrix multiplication goes wrong.

The solution therefore is to switch the arguments to `dynamics(t, x)`. Inside `dynamics` you can ignore the parameter `t` as long as your matrix `A` is not time-dependent.